# Can't write in input field, I'm using django and generating HTML from JS

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'll show you both my HTML and my JS code. Its simple by now, but this problem might be a challenge to all my project since I have several things that will work like this form. Apologies console.log message is in spanish, but it runs all the script. The problem is when i reach to the form itself i cant write anything, well you can write if you hold de click. Havent used any CSS, rather than the style thing on z i.

```js
const fillSection = (option = "user-registration", e ) => {
    console.log("you are filling section");
    console.log(e);
    
    const content = document.querySelector('#user-registration')
    switch (option) {
        case "user-registration":
            content.innerHTML =
            `<form id="user-registration-form" method="post" style="z-index: 1000 !important;">
                <div class="input-texts">
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <label for="name-user">Nombre</label>
                        <input id="name-user" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <label for="password-user">Password</label>
                        <input id="password-user" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <label for="email-user">Email</label>
                        <input id="email-user" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="submit-button" class="form-btn" type="submit">Register</button>
            </form>`;
        
            const sendDataForm = document.getElementById("submit-button");
            console.log("seleccionado el submit");
            sendDataForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {apiSendDataUser(e)});
        break;
    }
};


 const apiSendDataUser = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const formData = new FormData (event.target);
    fetch('https://127.0.0.1:8000/videoHub/post_user',{
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json());
} ;

const registerSectionButton = document.getElementById("user-registration");
registerSectionButton.addEventListener("click", () =>{fillSection("user-registration")});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="\..\static\index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" >
        <div id="subwrapper">
            <div id="topHead">
                
            </div>
            <div id="buttons">
                <button id="uploadFile">Subir un archivo</button>
                <button id="home">Página Principal</button>
                <button id="user-registration">Registrate o loggeate</button>
            </div>
            <section id="content">
                
            </section>
            <div id="right-top-banner">
                   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static\index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried with z index but isnt working... to be fair I dont know what to do, thanks for the help.

Comment: I doubt the code that you posted is the code that you are actually using with the javascript below your html and not being called. I recommend posting it in usable fashion you can use the `<>` in the text editor to post html and javascript seperately.  However, I'm going to skip past that and go right into the fact that you have a button with the ID of user-registration and then you are replacing the content of that button with **content.innerHTML**. I would maybe make a div and replace that div's innerHTML and not the button.

Comment: Yes, thanks you was that. Im leading the content not to the button but to the section on the html. Thanks, is sad but this took me a lot of time!

Comment: No problem. Although this isn't the problem, I do recommend learning to use CSS classes instead of IDs.  Classes are reusable and although you to create cleaner CSS when the time comes.